# Elasticsearch, find documents without matching documents containing value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Edit: Simplified my question

I have event logs streaming into a single elasticsearch index "logs".

Each of these event logs represents a single event in some long running process. The event log has a status say with values queued->init->running->finished.

Now I want to query my index for running jobs...but if I search for status="running", I'll also get jobs that have finished later on. As a human, I would look for logs with a "running" event but no "finished" event.

Say I had to rake my leaves, clean the house, and then eat lunch. My event logs look like:
i.e.

```
{job: "rake leaves" status: "queued"}
{job: "clean house" status: "queued"}
{job: "eat lunch" status: "queued"}
{job: "rake leaves" status: "started"}
{job: "rake leaves" status: "running"}
{job: "rake leaves" status: "finished"}
{job: "clean house" status: "started"}
{job: "clean house" status: "finished"}
{job: "clean house" status: "running"}
{job: "eat lunch" status: "started"}
{job: "eat lunch" status: "running"}
```

How do I find running jobs that have not finished? In this case, eat lunch 
is the only running job. I will be extending this to also look for queued jobs that have not started. The status is irrelevant.

My current line of thought is to use a reverse nested aggregation to bubble up all statuses, then filter out items I don't want from there. I could also probably misuse the terms aggregator with min_doc_count to get what I need.

Examples

```
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/jobs/" -d'
    {
       "mappings": {
          "event": {
             "properties": {
                "name": {
                   "type": "keyword"
                },
                "status": {
                   "type": "keyword"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }'
```

- Some sample data

```
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/jobs/_bulk" -d'
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job0", "status":"init"}
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job1", "status":"init"}
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job2", "status":"init"}
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job0", "status":"running"}
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job1", "status":"running"}
    {"index":{"_index":"jobs","_type":"event"}}
    {"name":"job0", "status":"finished"}
    '
```

- Sample Query

```
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET http://localhost:9200/logs/event/_search -d'
    {
        "aggs": {
            "duplicateNames": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "min_doc_count": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }' | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to be honest! I do understand the context and all. but, I dont quite get your question. what is the goal you want to achieve here?

Maybe at the end of your (nicely done explanation :D) put the question clearly at the end. :)

Comment: Hi there, I reformatted the question. I have log data that streams with job names and job status. I want to to search for jobs that are running but have not finished